# How to get access token from keycloack using postman GET request

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, keycloak

I'm new to keycloak and tyring to get access token from keycloak using GET request method through postman but experiencing http 405 error (Method not allow)

I already have tried this but it's not working and throwing HTTP 405 error method not allowed

```
MEHTOD: GET
URL: https://keycloak.carbook-dev.gocarbook.com/auth/realms/carbook/protocol/openid-connect/token
{
    "realm":"carbook",
    "bearer-only":true,
    "grant_type":"password",
    "client_id": "web_app",
    "username":"admin*****",
    "password":"a*****"
}
```

I'm expecting access token upon successfully completion of that request such as

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJJQk1YWTd0TGpfejg5c1p2Z2JrUHp.....

I can achieve the same using postman [GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MNjF.png) but i want to achieve this through rest call so that later on i could use the same request in cypress to access the token for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you POST the request instead of GET ?
The message seems to tell that GET method is not allowed for this endpoint...

Comment: I've been able to resolve this issue using POST request.   method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://keycloak.carbook-dev.gocarbook.com/auth/realms/carbook/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            form : true,
            body: {
                "username":username,
                "password":password,
                "grant_type":grant_type,
                "client_id": client_id         
            }